# Adding dynamic controls in `formGroup` is automatically sorting alphabetically

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups

I'm creating a dynamic `Form` using angular `formGroup` and `formcontrols` based on a `json` array like this:

```js
let input = ['name','zip_code' 'address', 'field1', 'custom_field'];
```

**app.component.ts**:

```js
public group: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});
    
  ngOnInit() {
    for(let field in input) {
    this.group.addControl(this.input[field], new FormControl('', []));
  }
  console.log(this.group.controls);
}
```

**console output:**

```sh
address: FormControl
custom_field: FormControl 
field1: FormControl 
name: FormControl 
zip_code: FormControl
```

**app. component.html**

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div *ngFor="let control of group.controls | keyvalue; let i = index">
    <text-field> </text-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

On the view the `form` fields are shows in alphabetical order.

Is there any way to **disable** that alphabetical sorting of fields?
I want to display the fields as *same sequence in array.*

Comment: Isn't it possible to use `*ngFor="let field of input"`?

Comment: No 
I put that question  in simple way but actually that input array can contain another formGroup or formArray, also there is a way to add/remove the fields dynamically, hence there is a lots of logic involved around the formGroup and I can't refer input array directly into view.

Comment: Problem is, objects in javascript (nothing to do with Angular) - do not have an order, only arrays do. So one way or the other, if order matters, you’d have to loop an array..

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array of `FormGroup` with `Object.keys()` after creating that for `ngFor`. Something like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from  '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  public input = ['name','zip_code', 'address', 'field1', 'custom_field'];

  public arrayForm: any[];

  public group: FormGroup 

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.group = this.formBuilder.group({});
    for (let field in this.input) {
       this.group.addControl(this.input[field], new FormControl('', []));
    }
  console.log(this.group.controls);
  this.arrayForm = Object.keys(this.group.controls)
  console.log(this.arrayForm)
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div *ngFor="let control of this.arrayForm; let i = index">
    {{control}}
    <input>
  </div>
</form>
```

I create a sample here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-vk7t8e?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) for you.